# Is a constant variable more performant when switching between widgets and if so how do you achieve this at the entry point of app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use the same code for both web and android.  Where the code differs I switch between widgets based on a global variable.

Is the performance worse when using a non constant / non final variable when switching between widgets? I'm thinking, because the variable is not final or constant and can be changed at any point, Flutter will not be able to optimise the code. Is that true? If inefficient, how do I make my code efficient?

eg.

I have two main files and set my AppType enum in each

**[appType.dart]**

```
AppType appType; //can't think of how to make this constant or final
```

**[android_main.dart]**

```
void main() {
  appType = AppType.and;
```

**[web_main.dart]**

```
void main() {
  appType = AppType.and;
```

In my widgets I switch where I need a widget specific for the web or android

```
if(appType == AppType.web)
  return MyWidgetWeb();
else
  return MyWeigetAnd();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a constant is more efficient, mainly because of tree-shaking.

Assume that you have the following types:

```dart
enum AppType {
  mobile,
  web,
}

class Mobile {}

class Web {}
```

Then when you write:

```dart
const type = AppType.web;

void main() {
  if (type == AppType.web) {
    print(Web());
  }
  else if (type == AppType.mobile) {
    print(Mobile());
  }
}
```

Then when compiling the code, the compiler knows that the `if` block will always be reached, and the `else if` never will.

As such:

- the conditions are removed. When compiled, the code will be:

  ```dart
  const type = AppType.web;

  void main() {
    // no `if` performed
    print(Web());
  }
  ```
- `Mobile` will not be bundled in the executable, so you have a lighter application.

---

To fully benefit from this behavior, you can use Dart "defines", using `int/bool/String.fromEnvironment`, which allows you to define constants that behave differently depending on some external build parameters.

The way such constant would look like is:

```dart
const isWeb = bool.fromEnvironment('isWeb', defaultValue: false);
```

Which you can then control using arguments on `flutter run` and `flutter build` commands:

```sh
flutter build <whatever> --dart-define=isWeb=true
```